# C# console local chat group

Tags: c#, filesystems, console-application, chat

I'm working on a C# console application that includes a chat group. I thought I had figured it out but it doesn't seems to work... I'm a total beginner, so the way I did it was to create a folder the program fills with .txt files with the message infos (no internet included). That worked to support the user/password/options part of the program but the chat is reacting weirdly. When you enter a message, it react and shows it on screen but when someone else post it you don't see it unless you restart the app. Here's the code:

```
chat_group:
        temp1I = Directory.GetFiles((message_folder + "\\1-Groupe"), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        temp1S = temp1I.ToString();
        System.IO.StreamReader ChatFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(message_folder + "\\1-Groupe\\" + temp1S + ".txt");
        counter = 0;
        while ((temp2S = ChatFile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            switch (counter)
            {
                case 0:
                    text = (temp2S + ": ");
                    WRITE_R();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    text = (temp2S);
                    WRITE();
                    break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        ChatFile.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("");
        test:
        if (File.Exists((message_folder + "\\1-Groupe\\" + (temp1S + 1) + ".txt")))
        {
            goto chat_group;
        }
        if ((temp3S = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            temp1S = (temp1I + 1).ToString();
            string[] ChatLines2 = { username, temp3S };
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(message_folder + "\\1-Groupe\\" + temp1S + ".txt", ChatLines2);
        }
        goto test;
```

Note: As it is a big application, I've not copy the variables but I ensure they are correct as they work on all the other parts of the app.

Comment: "Here's the code:"  *\*crickets\**

Comment: Sounds like you're not updating the UI when a new file is written to the directory - you'll want to look at [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx). Side note - you should stop using `goto` and labels. It has valid uses, but the above usecase **isn't** one of them.

Comment: here is the code, just pushed the wrong button ^^

Comment: Thx, I'll look at this FileSystemWatcher, what do you suggest instead of 'goto' I used to use functions but it caused loads of problems.

Comment: @H.Théo: In this case...you can get rid of the `goto`s with something like `chat_group: while (true) { ... all that code ... test: while (!File.Exists(...)) { if ((temp3S = Console.ReadLine()) != null) { ... } } }`. But you really ought to look into breaking the code up into functions.

Comment: @hnefatl I looked at the FileSystemWatcher methods but I do not know how to implement them... `//File Watcher System
            void WATCH()
            {
                FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
                watcher.Path = (message_folder + "\\1-Groupe\\" + (temp1S + 1) + ".txt");
                watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
                watcher.Filter = "*.*";
                watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            }`

Comment: I'm not reading that. Update the question with your findings.